# How to setup Azure AD App permission for downstream applications?

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We need Azure AD application permissions to be set for the scenario below.

There are multiple CLient Apps calling the Supporting App.
The Supporting app's role is to create abstraction around the Web API calls to make the Client apps light.

The problem is **we need to track** **which Client** app made the call when the call comes to the Application WebAPI from the supporting App.

**How should we register our applications in Azure AD to make it possible?**

- Do the ClientApp need to add application permissions to Supporting App and Application WebAPI ?
- Do the ClientApp need to add permission to Supporting App only and Supporting App needs to add permission to Application WebAPI?

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kartik. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

•   Since the client apps will be accessing the supporting app for specific tasks or calls or doing some function, the client apps should have access to the Supporting app’s API and data flow accordingly. The client apps should have permission to the supporting app’s API to call the web API through it. Thus, you would need to create **‘App roles’** and assign scopes to the client apps for accessing the supporting app API and further on, create **‘App roles’** and appropriate scopes to access the Web API from the supporting app.

•   Thus, you would need to register each of the client apps, supporting app and the Web API to be accessed through the supporting app in Azure AD. Once registered, please ensure that you have created the required **‘App roles’** for each client application and the client application is given permission to access the supporting application with the required scope through the **‘Application permission’**. Also, ensure that the supporting application credentials are included in the requests sent to the supporting app to access the Web API through it. Similarly, you would need to configure the above in supporting application API in Azure AD.

Please find the documentation link below which explains the above steps in detail for adding permission to access a Web API: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis